# ruby on rails - are there any packages or modules that are not written in pure ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, package

I am really new to ruby on rails. I heard ruby on rails needs to java virtual machine to be run.

I would like to ask some basic stuff about the ruby on rails.

It seems like ruby on rails can have some native code in the source code.

From what I have researched about ruby on rails, the code is usually runnable on the same platform that the code is written.

So when we need to run the code on different platform, using the Bundler ( rubygems ), it can automatically download the right version of package.

Is this correct??

Also, for the packages, are there any packages or modules that are not written in pure ruby??

I am not sure if there is any. If there is, I think the package manager cannot automatically download the right version and developers need to pull it out and make changes to deploy on the other machines.

I wasn't sure how to look at package dependencies in the package.
Is there a way to find the package dependency??

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not a place to explain the basics of a certain programming language. Come here with a specific code problem, show the efforts you've made to solve it, and we can talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what question you are asking however perhaps I can resolve some of your confusion.

Rails is a framework, distributed as a Ruby gem package which runs as part of a Ruby app on one of several available Ruby interpreters.

Neither Ruby nor Rails depend on the JVM. The [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) interpreter allows you to run Ruby code within the JVM if you choose to do so.

Many Ruby gems include native extensions which may be platform dependent. Bundler allows you to express platform specific dependencies in cases where you need to use different gems to supply the same interface on different platforms. Take a look at Bundler's [platform](http://bundler.io/v1.7/man/bundle-platform.1.html) command as a way to check if your current platform satisfies the requirements of a given gemfile.

For example the `sqlite3` gem requires native C extensions which cannot be compiled to run on the JRuby platform. Projects which support JRuby must swap in an alternative like the `activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` gem.

Comment: thank you so much! everything now starts making a sense to me.